# UI component Field Valiation issue in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, uicomponent

I have create a field in magento 2.1 with integer validation.

```
<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="integer" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
```

this lines of code works fine magento 2.3 for Integer validation but when i use this in magento 2.1 that treats it like required field + Integer value validation.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you want to apply integer validation?

Comment: yes, only interger. I dont know why magento 2.1 takes interger validation as required also.